# .not in jquery not working

Tags: jquery, css, html

After much of research over google and various forums, I am posting this question here.

I have 5 div elements like below -

```
<div id="domain1"></div>
<div id="domain2"></div>
<div id="domain3"></div>
<div id="domain4"></div>
<div id="domain5"></div>
```

When I click on one div, I want to hide rest of the divs.

For this, I wrote the code as -

```
$("#^='domain'").not(id).hide();
```

where id is a variable ( var id ) which dynamically holds the id of the clicked div element.

This hides all five div elements. This is not excluding the clicked div element.

Kindly help, where am I going wrong.

Comment: can you do a console.log(id) before the code executes to see how the string looks to verify it is correctly spelled and not null?

Comment: Are you putting `#` in the id variable?  If not you'll need to `not('#' + id)`

Comment: yes # would go in id variable.

Comment: @Andrei Yes I have verified id variable. It is showing up correctly

Comment: Can you include, in the question, the exact value of `id` as that's the most likely issue and just saying "yes, it's correct" doesn't help us or you.

Comment: lastly make sure your selector is correct. It's the last piece of code that could be going wrong. do a quick test via hardcoding "#domain1" in the not to make sure the selector is correct

Comment: Next, you should create a valid [mcve] with your code (use a code snippet in the question) showing it not working and explain what area you're having difficulty getting to work.  There's nothing wrong with your code *as presented* - we can very easily create a snippet/fiddle using your exact code and it would work as expected.

Comment: @freedomn-m
I did alert(id);
when I clicked <div id="domain1"></div>, the alert box popped up, showed #domian1. The same happened for rest of the divs.
Unfortunately, I am not able to upload any images. :(

Comment: As worded on the vote-to-close page:  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to *reproduce* it** in the question itself.

Comment: No need for images.  Are you sure it showed `#domian1` ?  (and not `#domain1`)?

Comment: I have been working on a peculiar multi level drop down menu design. This problem is a part of the flow. As I cannot share the exact code, I have described part of the code here.

Comment: @freedomn-m:  I am sorry. that was a typo above. it showed #domain1

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for matching the beginning of an ID `#^='domain'` was incorrect -- it's missing the `[]` brackets and uses `#` instead of `id`.

This is what you want:

```js
$('div').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  console.log(id); // note it does not include the #
  $("[id^='domain']").not('#'+id).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="domain1">1</div>
<div id="domain2">2</div>
<div id="domain3">3</div>
<div id="domain4">4</div>
<div id="domain5">5</div>
```

Comment: use toggle() rather than hide() -- otherwise, you can't bring the other divs BACK. ;)

Comment: Well, sure.  But that's not what they asked about.

Comment: I hastily typed a wrong value here in question. Edited the question for the right value.  # comes in with the id variable in my case. I have used  $("[id^='domain']").not(id).hide(); this was also hiding all the divs

Comment: OK, I removed the reference to the incorrect ID name from the answer.  The code you've put in the above comment doesn't match the code in your question; what's in the comment should work as you can see here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's .not() doing exactly what it should. Of course, I'm passing the clicked element itself, rather than trying to build an ID selector to match against.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").on("click", function(){
    var clickedEl = $(this);
    $("div").not(clickedEl).toggle();
    
    // OR ANOTHER WAY, if they're at the 
    //   same level in the DOM. Simply comment
    //   out the above, and uncomment the below
    //   to see the same result.
    //
    //clickedEl.siblings("div").toggle();
  })
})
```

```css
div {
  height: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  background-color: #FFA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="domain1">a</div>
<div id="domain2">b</div>
<div id="domain3">c</div>
<div id="domain4">d</div>
<div id="domain5">e</div>
```